# Complete QtQuick Localization on PySide

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside2, qt-quick

I know there is nearly the same question posted on [Localization in QtQuick from top to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44578113/localization-in-qtquick-from-top-to-bottom) but the guy there already knows how to start off, further on it's based on C++.

In my problem, I also have to translate all strings on QML side in real-time, but Python (PySide) is used in the backend instead of C++. And since I am quite a newbie in this section, I don't know how to achieve this with minimal Python use.

Based on the linked question, I am so far able to:

- Appended QT_TR_NOOP() to all of my translatable strings for translation at runtime.

But the further steps described there are not clear to me. The documentation of QML for Python is very minimalistic.

I would be very thankful for some detailed descriptions or examples.

Comment: @eyllanesc pyside 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is similar to what is done in C++ since QML does not change anything, you only have to adapt the logic in python.

The step is as follows:

1. Generate the .ts from qml using lupdate.

   ```
   lupdate main.qml -ts i18n_es.ts
   ```
2. Use Qt Linguist to add the translations.
3. Compile the .ts to .qm using lrelease.

   ```
   lrelease i18n_es.ts i18n_es.qm
   ```
4. Load the .qm using python.

```
├── main.py
├── qml
│   └── main.qml
└── translations
    ├── i18n_es.qm
    ├── i18n_es.ts
    ├── i18n_fr.qm
    └── i18n_fr.ts
```

**main.py**

```py
import os
import re
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PySide2.QtCore import (
    Property,
    QCoreApplication,
    QDir,
    QObject,
    Qt,
    QTranslator,
    QUrl,
    Signal,
    Slot,
)
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication, QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
QML_DIRECTORY = CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "qml"
TRANSLATIONS_DIR = CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "translations"


class Translator(QObject):
    language_changed = Signal(name="languageChanged")

    def __init__(self, engine, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._engine = engine
        self._languages_model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.load_translations()
        self._translator = QTranslator()

    @Slot(str)
    def set_language(self, language):
        if language != "Default":
            trans_dir = QDir(os.fspath(TRANSLATIONS_DIR))
            filename = trans_dir.filePath(f"i18n_{language}.qm")
            if not self._translator.load(filename):
                print("Failed")
            QGuiApplication.installTranslator(self._translator)
        else:
            QGuiApplication.removeTranslator(self._translator)
        self._engine.retranslate()

    def languages_model(self):
        return self._languages_model

    languages = Property(QObject, fget=languages_model, constant=True)

    def load_translations(self):
        self._languages_model.clear()
        item = QStandardItem("Default")
        self._languages_model.appendRow(item)
        trans_dir = QDir(os.fspath(TRANSLATIONS_DIR))
        for filename in trans_dir.entryList(["*.qm"], QDir.Files, QDir.Name):
            language = re.search(r"i18n_(.*?)\.qm", filename).group(1)
            item = QStandardItem(language)
            self._languages_model.appendRow(item)


def main():
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    translator = Translator(engine, app)

    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("translator", translator)
    filename = os.fspath(QML_DIRECTORY / "main.qml")
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)

    def handle_object_created(obj, obj_url):
        if obj is None and url == obj_url:
            QCoreApplication.exit(-1)

    engine.objectCreated.connect(handle_object_created, Qt.QueuedConnection)
    engine.load(url)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Title")

    ListModel {
        id: list_model

        ListElement {
            name: QT_TR_NOOP("house")
        }

        ListElement {
            name: QT_TR_NOOP("table")
        }

        ListElement {
            name: QT_TR_NOOP("chair")
        }

    }

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        ComboBox {
            model: translator ? translator.languages : null
            textRole: "display"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            onActivated: function(index) {
                translator.set_language(currentText);
            }
        }

        Button {
            text: qsTr("name")
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }

        ListView {
            model: list_model
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true

            delegate: Text {
                text: qsTr(name)
            }

        }

    }

}
```

<sub>The full example is [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/68528179).</sub>

Comment: thank you very much for your effort. This is quite it what I need! What I am not sure about is how to exactly run the commands lupdate and lrelease ? Are these two commands to use in a terminal window? Because I have to work on a Windows Machine...

Comment: @thsolyt That tool comes with Qt so you have to install Qt5 (check that you don't install Qt6).

Comment: I could use `lupdate` and `lrelease` successfully. I tried out your example but I have the problem that the Gui does not refresh to the new language. It just stays in english... Do you have any suggestion what the reason could be?

Comment: Further on, as mentioned in the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-internationalization.html#9-prepare-for-dynamic-language-changes), I tried to emit a signal whenever `set_language` is called and leaving out `self._engine.retranslate` , but also without success.

Comment: @thsolyt Could you upload your project (I mean my code with your .ts and .qm) to github to see where the error is?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the reason. There is a problem when generating the .ts and .qm files. Since I am using PySide 2, I used pyside2-lupdate for the .ts file since this command is directly available in my venv. But for lrelease there is no pyside2 version. And the mix of those caused the problem. Now using pure lupdate and lrelease, the code works. Thank you.

Comment: @thsolyt If my answer helped you then don't forget to mark it as correct (for more information check the [tour])

Comment: I did it :) a further question I would have: if I have a string property on python side and use it on qml, how could this be translated? For example `qsTr(translator.exampleString)` where `exampleString` is a string property defined on python side.